A transistor latch in dual-supply
I need to build a few latches they are supplied from +rail and -rail.
When the latch is ON it should output strong +Vrail and -Vrail also (not through resistor).
A solution on picture comes to my mind.
I think latch can be Set by temporary pushing the current to the base through diode and Reset by shorting the base to appropriate rail with additional transistor.
Could it work? Or is there some another solution?


Have you simulated this circuit? If not, why not. If you have simulated it, where are the sim results?

What is the intended load current? Above 20 mA transistor HFE is a critical factor.

@Jens It’s just for driving two RC circuits (10k, 330n) after pressing a button. I need to both side goes simultaneously and have same time constant.
